# replace string character (') to (-) in pandas and change it to datetime

Tags: pandas, dataframe

i have dataset df like below;

```
  A  
June'11
July'12
2018-02-01
```

anyone can help me to replace (') character to (-)
iam confuse to use pandas code

```
 df['A'].replace(''', '-', inplace=True)  ???
```

After i have changed the (') string i want to change the A column type to datetime
Thank in advance

Comment: `df['A']=df['A'].replace("'", '-',regex=True) `

Comment: `df['A']=df['A'].str.replace("'", '-')`

Comment: Handri,  are you getting an error while using replace?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below:

```
>>> df
          A
0     June'11
1     July'12
2  2018-02-01
>>> df.replace({'\'': '-'}, regex=True)
          A
0     June-11
1     July-12
2  2018-02-01
```

OR

If its specific to a column `A` then.

```
>>> df['A'].str.replace(r"[\']", "-")
0       June-11
1       July-12
2    2018-02-01
```

OR

```
>>> df['A'].str.replace("'", "-")
0       June-11
1       July-12
2    2018-02-01
```